# requests beautifulsoup parsing a value from a select tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm looking to modify my existing code which currently parses `td` attributes of a webpage source, and switch that out for the `value` of an `option` field equals a numerical value. Let me explain

```
import requests, re, collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_content(url):
    if type(url) != str:
        print('You need to included a string')
        exit()
    else:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
            'From': 'user@umbc.edu'  
        }
        req  = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        current_month=soup.find_all('td', {'id': 'monatevent'})
        fwk_nextmonth=soup.find_all('td', {'id': 'aevent'})
        curr_month = []
        fwk_next_month = []
```

I want to now parse the following `select` `option` attribute to alert when `option value=08` for example:

```
<select name="month" onchange="submit()">
<option value="09" selected="">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option>
</select>
```

It appears if I use the following selector in my code, that nothing is returned:
current_month=soup.find_all('select', {'option': '08'})

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Can you post expected output?..in the example I do not see `'option': '08'`

Comment: current_month=soup.find_all('select', {'option': '08'}), In find_all method you have to provide attrs as second parameter option is not an attribute it is tag, you have to first take option as tag then try to find the value.

Comment: @utks009 - can you show that in a full answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors built-in within BeautifulSoup. Selector `option[selected]` will find tag `<option>` with attribute `selected`:

```
data = """<select name="month" onchange="submit()">
<option value="09" selected="">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option>
</select>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('option[selected]').text)
```

Prints:

```
09
```

Edit:

```
If you want to find option with value=08, you can do CSS selector `option[value=08]`:

data = """<select name="month" onchange="submit()">
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09" selected="">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option>
</select>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('option[value=08]'))
```

Prints:

```
<option value="08">08</option>
```

Comment: Don't assume `selected` is set or not. Do assume that anywhere in an `<option>` that `08` occurs that this is what I want. e.g. `<option value=09>`

Comment: thanks for this. Last question: how would i check if soup.select_one() evalutes to true?

Comment: if `select_one()` doesn't find anything it returns `None`, so simply check it for `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to find the value of selected option, as from html string.
May be this help..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = """<select name="month" onchange="submit()">
<option value="09" selected="">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option>
</select>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html.parser')

select = soup.find('select')
for option in select.find_all('option'):
    if option.has_attr('selected'):
        print('Value:', option.get('value'))
```

Comment: Please dont assume the value has an option on `selected` it could be any `option` whether `selected` is true or not. How does this change your code? Thanks again

Comment: @Jshee, You can remove this condition if option.has_attr('selected'):, and you will get all values. The output is in format `Value: 09` `Value: 10` `Value: 11`